# Styles being injected many times by sass-loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I am using Vue with `sass-loader` and am having an issue with the same styles getting injected many, many times into the page. I am using SCSS and have tried importing all the partials into one SCSS stylesheet, and importing that into my `main.js` file and letting Webpack handle it, but it is still doing the same thing. I've tried importing each partial individually into my Vue config file, and nothing has changed.

[image: repeating style tags]
(all of these style tags repeat)

This is my current configuration:

`vue.config.js`

```js
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        scss: {
            additionalData: `
                @import "@/styles/_variables.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_buttons.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_default.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_grid.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_mixins.scss";
                @import "@/styles/_utilities.scss";
            `
        }
    }
},
```

Previous `vue.config.js` configuration:

```js
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
            prependData: '@import "~@/styles/styles.sass"'
        },
        scss: {
            prependData: '@import "~@/styles/styles.scss";'
        }
    }
},
```

A previous configuration:

`styles.scss`

```css
@import '_variables';
@import '_default';
@import '_grid';
@import '_mixins';
@import '_buttons';
@import '_utilities';
```

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import './styles/styles.scss';


new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

`package.json`:

```js
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "npm": "^6.14.7",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.4.6",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "sass-loader": "^9.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.3",
    "vue-markdown-loader": "^2.4.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing in my projects.

But i assume it's not a Bug.  The number of inserts these styles will be equal to the number of components where these styles are used. Each insert will have its own hash like [data-v-df8c9814], which is a hash of particular component.

Comment: Many years later (yikes), I don't use Vue anymore, but that logic makes complete and total sense.